# hola buenos dias estoy confundida con esto gracias, puede parecer tonto y basico pero he intentado varias cosas y me sale mal

Tags: javascript

Imagina que has salido a comer con tus cuatro mejores amigas. La cuenta total del consumo es de 50 dólares, pero a eso debes agregarle el 10% de Impuesto al Valor Agregado (IVA). Quieres dividir la cuenta equitativamente entre las cinco. Para eso vamos a crear este programa.

El ejercicio incluye un boilerplate (plantilla) que ya incluye una función (restaurantBill), la cual espera recibir un argumento (bill) con el monto de la cuenta antes de impuestos (un número), y espera que retornemos un string con la cantidad que le toca pagar a cada una ya teniendo en cuenta el 10% de impuestos (e incluyendo el símbolo de dólar).

El boilerplate (plantilla):

```
const restaurantBill = (bill) => {
  const tax = /* ??? */

  /* ??? */

  return /* ??? */
};
```

Sigue los pasos a continuación para completar la implementación de la función restaurantBill.

Asigna el resultado de multiplicar bill por 10% en la variable tax (impuesto en inglés). Tip: 10% en decimal se escribe 0.1.
Crea una variable llamada total y asígnale el resultado de sumar bill más tax.
Retorna el monto que cada una debe pagar (total divido entre 5), con el símbolo $ adelante (por ejemplo: $11). Tip: puedes usar concatenación de strings (o string literals) para crear un string con el número y el símbolo $ adelante.

Comment: También estaría bien que cambiaras el título de la pregunta por uno que se enfoque más al problema, uno más objetivo.

Comment: La pregunta debería incluir qué has intentado hasta ahora y el error que obtienes. El título debería ser algo como "obtengo el error X cuando hago Y", no algo tan genérico.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te ayude, si no entiendes alguna parte puedes preguntarme lo que sea, saludos.

```
const restaurantBill = (bill) => {
  const tax = bill * 0.1 //bill multiplicado por 10% (0.1), 
                         //se calcula el impuesto del total a pagar

  const total = bill + tax // cuenta inicial + el impuesto

  return `Cada una debera pagar $ ${total / 5}`
};

console.log(restaurantBill(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco realice el mismo ejercicio y pude lograrlo bajo el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
const restaurantBill = (bill) => {
  const tax = (bill * 0.1); /* Valor del 10% de la factura */
  const total = bill + tax; // Valor total de la factura con el impuesto


  return `$${total / 5}`;/* ??? */
};


module.exports = restaurantBill;
```

Comment: Muy buen día, perdona que no lo haya colocado en código, soy nueva aquí y no pude editarlo!

Comment: Lee [answer]: _¿qué hace este código?_ Además, procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad: ten en cuenta que aquí no se hacen tareas, y el OP (autor de la pregunta) no ha demostrado esfuerzo en resolverla.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funciono de esta forma soy nueva en esto espero les sirva.

```
const restaurantBill = (bill) =>{
const tax = (bill*0.1);
const total = bill+tax;

return '$' + total/5;
};
module.exports = restaurantBill;
```